# .NET - preview Excel files (XP)

Tags: .net, excel, preview

Is there any method to preview Excel files on XP besides WebBrowser control? How does the WebBrowser itself preview them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is discussed [here](http://xldennis.wordpress.com/2007/11/16/open-excel-workbooks-in-vbnet-solutions/), and it seems there are several other options (not including 3rd party components).

Answer (score 0):

The WebBrowser itself is a Microsoft IE component and hence with a page that loads an ActiveX under the browser, the ActiveX control interacts with the MS-Office's Excel library via InterOp to display the Excel Spreadsheet on the page...The other option is to obtain a library that can read the Excel in a raw native binary format, that is interpret the binary structure and decipher what it means before showing the data...

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of Office have a limited functionality ActiveX control (Office Web Control / OWC) which can display an Excel workbook in the browser. Excel 2007 dropped support for the OWC controls.

Excel 2010 is adding new web controls which can display a spreadsheet in the browser. However, these new controls depend on Microsoft Office Sharepoint Server 2010.

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) is an Excel compatible spreadsheet component for .NET which includes a [Windows Forms Control](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/windowsforms.aspx) which can read / write / edit / calculate / display / print / etc... Excel workbooks in .NET applications.

SpreadsheetGear can also display images from Excel charts or ranges of cells as demonstrated by the ASP.NET samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/imaging.aspx).

You can download a free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) if you want to try SpreadsheetGear yourself.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Comment: Thanks Joe, I will definitely consider implementing SpreadsheetGear into my project.